# Ошибка при <include> yandex.map

Tags: java, android, map

Есть две активности:
Map Yandex.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private MapView mapview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MapKitFactory.setApiKey("censored");
    MapKitFactory.initialize(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapview = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapview.getMap().move(
            new CameraPosition(new Point(55.751574, 37.573856), 11.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0),
            null);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapview.onStop();
    MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapview.onStart();
    MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
}
```

И еще одна, с которой начинается прогрузка экрана.
Ее layout :

....

```
        <include layout="@layout/activity_maps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"/>
```

....

Вылетает ошибки:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.rdv.slcard:layout/fragment_home: Binary XML file line #8 in com.rdv.slcard:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.rdv.slcard:layout/activity_maps: Error inflating class com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Что я не так раздуваю?

**UPDATE**

Лаяут первой активности

```
<com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".ui.maps.MapsActivity"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**UPDATE V.2.0**

Желательно конечно, чтобы через фрагмент шел, но тоже чето говорит не то

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:name="com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.maps.MapsActivity"
/>
```

Когда меняю :

```
<com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".ui.maps.MapsActivity"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

На обычный Button или TextView - все гуд. Ничего не могу понять. Не может же быть так, что Яндекс не учел `<include>`

Comment: 23 cтрока - это <include ....
Лаяют второй активности включает в себя другие элементы, просто убрал, чтобы не мешал

Comment: покажите `layout/activity_maps` пожалуйста

Comment: Обновил вопрос)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Яндекс карты не поддерживают `<include>` активности с картой.
Не пользуйтесь Яндекс картами,если есть возможность. В нем кучу косяков, мало документации, нет поддержки и куча еще страшных вещей. GoogleMap +50$ гораздо лучше для хороших проэктов